# PHP shell_exec 'wkhtmltopdf' returns null even though successful completion

Tags: php, linux, apache, wkhtmltopdf, shell-exec

In the [docs for PHP shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php) it says that that shell_exec function will return `null` if an error occurs.  Unfortunately when I run the following code, the code all completes correctly, but the shell_exec command still returns `null`.

```
// convert to PDF
$output = shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter report.html report.pdf');
if (is_null($output)){
    echo("error creating pdf, please contact IT administrator.");
}
```

I can tell it completes correctly because 1) the PDF file is created correctly, and 2) because I check the apache error_log (which for some reason contains the output for the wkhtmltopdf command) and the output says each step of the process completed correctly.

This is a problem because I can't tell from the PHP program if the command completed correctly or not.  So the above script always dies with the error message even though no error occurred.

This is the output is the apache error log (which is identical the the output on the command line when executing directly from the command line):
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?  or how I can do this differently to correctly report the errors?

> Linux Ubuntu 12.10
>
> PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9

Comment: use `exec()` instead and capture the output and return value. possibly it's "working", but throwing warnings and a non-"success" return value.

Comment: just tried it, and still has the same behavior.  Output goes to apache error log and the exec() command returns null.